# Where can I see the European car tolls for the route?

Tags: europe, automobiles, tolls

For a route that goes from Country A, going through countries B, C, D and arriving to Country E, all of them in Europe, what is the easiest way to know what taxes I have to pay as car driver?

Of course, I could search for each country regulations, but I am wondering if there is a place where all this information is aggregated nicely (either an app or just a "cheat sheet" with all of these put in a compact manner).

While calculating an estimation would be quite a handy thing, I am wondering if there is an app to automatically tell you something like this:

> Your route goes throught these countries: country A, B, C:
>
> - Country A: does not have tolls
> - Country B: has toll barriers
> - Country C: you need this type of document/toll, and you can buy it `[here](LINK_TO_OFFICIAL_WEBSITE)`

Comment: Good question, I have also looked for such a thing, but I am afraid that you will also find out that no such service exists. It would also be difficult to properly support all the different toll models and country-specific ifs and whens in such a service. Most countries charge a flat toll for a specific time period, other countries per distance driven and then you have a few countries with very complex systems like e.g. the toll barriers in Norway, where in Oslo each barrier has at least 13 different tariffs depending on type of car (gas/diesel/electric) time of day and payment method.

Answer (score 3):

[Via Michelin](https://www.viamichelin.co.uk/) does provide an estimate of the total costs for particular routes.  The "top-line" figure given includes fuel, tolls, and vignettes;  but the site also provides a breakdown for each of these three costs, and you can get more information about the cost breakdown for a given itinerary by clicking on the "Cost Details for Your Trip" button attached to each itinerary.  [Here's an example.](https://www.viamichelin.co.uk/web/Itinerary-cost?departure=28001%20Madrid%2C%20Community%20of%20Madrid%2C%20Spain&departureTid=city-1243846&arrival=10011%20Bucharest%2C%20Romania&arrivalTid=city-1982404&index=0&vehicle=0&type=0&distance=km&currency=EUR&highway=false&toll=false&vignette=false&orc=false&crossing=true&caravan=false&shouldUseTraffic=false&withBreaks=false&break_frequency=7200&coffee_duration=1200&lunch_duration=3600&diner_duration=3600&night_duration=32400&car=hatchback&fuel=petrol&fuelCost=1.758&allowance=0&corridor=&departureDate=&arrivalDate=&fuelConsumption=6.8:5.6:5.6&shouldUseNewEngine=false)

Disclaimer:  I do not know whether this site is generally accurate, or how/whether it takes into account the confounding variables discussed in the comments.

Comment: I checked the website and it's so amazing! However, I cannot seem to find a way to discover the official websites where I can buy the tolls. It would be great to have a mapping between country names and their official websites to save on fees from third-party apps. E.g. for Hungary, I buy it from the Hungarian website, but if I would buy it via a third-party app, it would cost aroun 1-2 EUR more.

Comment: When it comes to the toll barriers I mentioned in Oslo, Via Michelin does not seem to know about them at all.

Answer (score 1):

To view the estimated toll price:

- https://calculator.tollsmart.com/: North America, Western Europe and [these countries](https://www.tollsmart.com/coverage/).
- https://www.tolls.eu/: toll + vignette prices For each European country.
- https://tollguru.com/
- Waze in Latvia, Slovenia, Spain and several non-European countries.

More info on Waze below:

---

https://support.google.com/waze/answer/9370512?hl=en:

> Toll prices are only available in Australia, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Dominican Republic, Israel, **Latvia**, New Zealand, Peru, Poland, Puerto Rico, **Slovenia**, **Spain**, Uruguay, and the US.

[image]

[image]